# How to get partitioned tables' partition keys

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, postgresql-14

```sql
select 
    relname as partitioned_tables
from pg_class
where relkind = 'p';
```

I get partitioned_tables with the code.
I need to get information about these tables' partition types (range,hash,list etc.) and partition column names.

Solution:

```sql
select pg_class.relname from pg_class inner join 
pg_partitioned_table on pg_class.oid = pg_partitioned_table.partrelid where pg_partitioned_table.partstrat = 'r';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you have to consult the system catalog [`pg_partitioned_table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-partitioned-table.html). `partstrat` contains the partitioning strategy, `partattrs` the column numbers of the partitioning key columns and `partexprs` contains the parsed form of the parttioning expressions for the entries with 0 in `partattrs`.

Comment: I wrote this query and it is work: ` select pg_class.relname from pg_class inner join pg_partitioned_table on pg_class.oid = pg_partitioned_table.partrelid where pg_partitioned_table.partstrat = 'r'; `